# Thread safe way to invalidate session

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, jax-rs

It's not clear to me what the appropriate way to invalidate a `session` is to guarantee a runtime exception isn't thrown if multiple concurrent threads are accessing the code path.

For the sake of this discussion, assume I have multiple incoming requests to logout, and they have a shared session.

*Approach 1:* Simply invalidate the session.

```
session.get().invalidate()
```

Would result in a `RuntimeException` if two threads successfully attained the original session and both called `invalidate()` as invalidate can only called once per session.

*Approach 2:* Get a mutex for the session

Further, it's not even possible to get a mutex to `synchronize` on here because:

```
synchronize(WebUtils.getSessionMutex(session.get())) {
    if (session.get(false) != null) {
         session.invalidate();
    }
}
```

This approach has the same exact problem as approach 1.  If two threads gain access to the shared session, the call to `getSessionMutex` (reference: ) will result in a `RuntimeException` because it would result on a call of `getAttribute` on an invalidated session.

*Approach 3*: Caching an object to synchronize on.

Get the original session id from the incoming request.  Use this id to cache an object for the purpose of synchronization.

This works but it seems like a lot of overhead.

**Hopefully someone has an Approach 4 that is more succinct.**

Comment: why can't you just catch an exception?

Comment: That's a valid suggestion.  You hear advisement against using exception catching as a replacement for control flow -- so if there was a way to do it without a `try` `catch` block in a reliable way then that would be preferential in my opinion.